# unity - Analog value on display arrow

Tags: unity-game-engine

how do I modify the code when I type the value 990 into the box so that the hand points to 970?  Analog value on display arrow

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class barometer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxValue = 0.0f; 
    public float minArrowAngle;
    public float maxArrowAngle;
    public RectTransform arrow; // The arrow 
    public float value = 0.0f;
    public Text valueLabel;

    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    

 if (valueLabel != null)
  valueLabel.text = ((int)value) + " hPa";
            
  if (arrow != null)
 arrow.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Lerp(minArrowAngle, maxArrowAngle, value / maxValue));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused .. so why should it point to something 20 units smaller than the input value?

Comment: I want to achieve that where I write the value, for example 970, so that the orange arrow points to the dial 970. Do not notice the other black arrows. Thank you for the advice v

Comment: no one can advise